# Does the coproduct preserve limits?

Tags: category-theory, fixed-point-theorems, limits-colimits, fixed-points

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with coproducts (+) and all limits.

For a diagram $D : \mathcal{I} \to \mathcal{C}$ is the following true?

$A+ \varprojlim_{i \in \mathcal{I}}  D(i) \cong \varprojlim_{i \in \mathcal{I}} (A + D(i))$

In words, is it true that the coproduct preserves limits? If not, would it be true that it preserves $\omega$-limits? The reason why I think it should be is because $LA \cong A + LA$ has a greatest solution, but I can't seem to be able to show that $A+(-)$ is continuous.

Comment: Consider intersections and direct sums. The do not behave well together.

Comment: Take in $\mathbf{Set}$ a singleton $\{*\}$ as $A$, take $\mathcal I$ the set $\mathbb N$ as a discrete category and $D(i)=\{*\}$, then $\lim_{i\in\mathcal I}D(i)=\prod_{i\in\mathbb N}\{*\}\simeq *$, so $A+\lim_{i\in\mathcal I}D(i)\simeq\{*\}$. But, $A+D(i)=\{*\}+\{*\}\simeq\{0,1\}$ and $\lim_{i\in\mathcal I}\{0,1\}=\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}\simeq\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$

Comment: I understand your point. However, I am pretty sure $LA = \nu X. A + X$ exists: it can be easily defined in Agda or Coq using Coinductive types. Then how do you construct it?

Comment: Just to be clear: When you say "$LA\cong A+LA$ has a greatest solution", you are looking for a terminal coalgebra for the functor $F\colon C\to C$ given by $F(X) = A+X$?

Comment: @Alessandro This is not a comment, it is a full answer. Just saying.

Comment: @AlexKruckman yes I was looking for the greatest fixed point.

Comment: thanks everyone, your comments have been very helpful and led me to the solution. I hope my answer below is correct.

Comment: The dual property holds in any cartesian closed category.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang, what do you mean? yes, I would expect $(A+-)$ to preserve colimits since $+$ is left adjoint. I don't understand your point about CCCs.

Comment: The dual property is "$X\mapsto X\times A$ preserves  colimits". This is true in a CCC because the the functor in question is a left adjoint. Contra your last comment, $X\mapsto X+A$ is *never* a left adjoint unless $A=0$, because it fails to preserve the initial object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking about the functor $F\colon C\to C$ given by $F(X) = X+A$ for a fixed object $A\in C$. When $C = \mathsf{Set}$, this functor does indeed preserve $\omega$-limits, which is sufficient for the construction of a terminal $F$-coalgebra (a greatest fixed-point of $F$).

More generally, whenever $C$ is an [extensive category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extensive+category), $F$ preserves [connected limits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/connected+limit). To see this, note that for any connected diagram with objects $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ in $C$, there is a natural map $(\varprojlim X_i)+A\to \varprojlim(X_i+A)$ coming from the universal properties of the limit and the coproduct. We just need to construct the inverse map $\varprojlim(X_i+A)\to (\varprojlim X_i)+A$. Let $Z =\varprojlim(X_i+A)$. For all $i$, we have the projection map $\pi_i\colon Z\to (X_i+A)$. Since $C$ is extensive, pulling back the inclusions $X_i\to (X_i+A)$ and $A\to (X_i+A)$ along $\pi_i$ gives subobjects $B_i\to Z$ and $C_i\to Z$ such that $Z\cong B_i+C_i$, with arrows $f_i\colon B_i\to X_i$ and $g_i\colon C_i\to A$. Now whenever there is an arrow $h\colon X_i\to X_j$ in the diagram, we get a big diagram in which all the squares are pullbacks:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
B_i @>>> Z @<<< C_i\\
@V{f_i}VV @V{\pi_i}VV @VV{g_i}V\\
X_i @>>> X_i+A @<<< A\\
@V{h}VV @V{h+\text{id}_A}VV @VV{\text{id}_A}V\\
X_j @>>> X_j+A @<<< A
\end{CD}$$
It follows that $B_i = B_j$, $C_i = C_j$, $h\circ f_i = f_j$, and $g_i = g_j$. Since the diagram is connected, all the $B_i$ are equal to a single object $B$, and the arrows $f_i$ give a cone over the diagram $(X_i)_{i\in I}$, which induces an arrow $f\colon B\to \varprojlim X_i$. And since the diagram is connected, all the $C_i$ are equal to a single object $C$, and all the $g_i$ are equal to a single arrow $g\colon C\to A$. The arrows $f$ and $g$ induce an arrow $f+g\colon Z\cong B+C \to (\varprojlim X_i) +A$, as desired.

On the other hand, as shown in the comments, $F$ does not preserve arbitrary limits, even when $C = \mathsf{Set}$. And for an arbitrary category $C$, $F$ does not even preserve $\omega$-limits. For example, let $C$ be a poset with $(X_i)_{i\in \omega}$ a descending chain of elements with meet $\bot$, and $A$ a non-top element such that $A\vee X_i = \top$ for all $i$. Then $A\vee \inf(X_i) = A$, but $\inf(A\vee X_i) = \top$.

Comment: The level of abstraction here makes the answer a bit hard to understand. Wouldn't it work with just bicartesian or cartesian closed categories?

Comment: @Markix What makes you think it would work with bicartesian or cartesian closed categories?

Comment: My point is that it is very unusual in natural categories for the "add $A$" functor to preserve limits. Now in Set, it happens to preserve $\omega$-limits but not arbitrary limits. Ok, so we can either accept this as a random property of the category of sets, or we can look for a more abstract theorem that explains and generalizes this "coincidence" to other categories. The most natural abstraction I found is the one I explained in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers! just to make sure when you say $\omega$-limits you mean $\omega^\text{op}$-limits? (also in the example about partial orders)

Comment: @Markix That's right. I was just following the terminology in your original post, where you asked about $\omega$-limits (but presumably you meant limits indexed by $\omega^{op}$).

Comment: @Markix If this answer settles your question, you can accept it by clicking the green check mark on the left. Welcome to Math Stackexchange!

Answer (score 1):

The functor (A + -) does not preserve all limits, but it does preserve the limit for the diagram $D : \omega^\text{op} \to \mathcal{C}$ with $D(i) = F^{i}_A 1$, $D(f : i \leftarrow i+1) = F^{i}_A f$ and $F_A X = A + X$. For $i=0$, $D(f) = !$.

The trick is to notice that $\lim_{n \in \omega^\text{op}} F^{n}_A 1$ in **Set**  contains only elements of the form $\langle *, *, \dots, *, a, a, a, \dots \rangle $ where $a \in A$. In particular, the first element $a \neq *$ determines all the following ones. (1 in **Set** is $\{*\}$). This is because the projection maps of the limit have to commute with the maps in the sequence.

Now, $\Phi : (A + \lim_{n \in \omega^\text{op}} F^{n}_A 1) \to \lim_{n \in \omega^\text{op}} F^{n}_A 1$  is the unique map into the limit noticing that
$A + \lim_{n \in \omega^\text{op}} F^{n}_A 1$ is a cone for the diagram $D$ (by applying $(A + -)$ to the limit and adding the map into $1$).

The other direction $\Psi :  \lim_{n \in \omega^\text{op}} F^{n}_A 1 \to (A + \lim_{n \in \omega^\text{op}} F^{n}_A 1)$ is obtained by
taking an element of the limit
$l = \langle *, *, \dots, *, a, a, a, \dots \rangle$ to $\text{inj}_1 (a)$ if the second component is $a$ or $\text{inj}_2 (l)$ otherwise (where $\mathit{inj}_i$ are the injections into the coproduct).

It is easy to check that $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are inverses by using the fact that once an element is fixed it cannot be changed.

Comment: +1. But some critiques: You stated the question for an arbitrary category $C$, but the answer only addresses the case $C = \mathsf{Set}$. Your description of the elements of the limit isn't very precise: The object $F_A^n 1$ is $1 + n\times A$, with $n$ copies of $A$. So an element needs to be labeled by which copy of $A$ it's in. I would describe an element of the limit as $\langle *,*,\dots\rangle$ (all $*$s) or $\langle *, *, \dots, *, (0,a), (1,a), (2,a), \dots\rangle$. Elements are uniquely determined by the number of $*$s and an element of $A$, so the limit is $1+\mathbb{N}\times A$.

Comment: Finally, in the case that $l$ does not have an $a$ in its second component, the map $\Psi$ should take $l$ to $\text{inj}_2(l')$, where $l'$ is obtained from $l$ by deleting a leading $*$.

Comment: I think you're right for the most part. Just one thing, the elements of the limit are either all $*$ or $\langle *, *, *, (n, a), (n,a)...\rangle$.. I think.

Comment: Well, it depends on how you index. But if the elements of the "new" copy of $A$ in $F_A^n 1$ are labeled by $(n,a)$, then they map to the elements $(n-1,a)$ in $F_A^{n-1}1$ under the connecting map $F_A^n!$. This "shift by 1" behavior is what leads to the isomorphism $1+\mathbb{N}\times A+A\cong 1+\mathbb{N}\times A$ in the limit.